# MySQL database cleanse using stored function, procedure

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tel_1` text,
  `tel_2` text,
  `tel_3` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

+----+------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+-------+
| id | tel_1                              | tel_2                                         | tel_3 |
+----+------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+-------+
|  1 | 123-412-3455                       | １２７６ー３６４７３９−１８１                 | NULL  |
|  2 | 714-212-3839 Not Using             | No Info                                       | NULL  |
|  3 | 12+13E                             | NULL                                          | NULL  |
|  4 | ０１２３ー3432-1233 Ext : 602      | NULL                                          | NULL  |
+----+------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+-------+
```

And I'd like to cleanse the data something like this below:

```
+----+--------------+------------+---------------+------------+-------+------------+
| id | tel_1        | tel_1_desc | tel_2         | tel_2_desc | tel_3 | tel_3_desc |
+----+--------------+------------+---------------+------------+-------+------------+
|  1 | 1234123455   | NULL       | 1276364739181 | NULL       | NULL  | NULL       |
|  2 | 7142123839   | Not Using  | NULL          | No Info    | NULL  | NULL       |
|  3 | 12+13E       | NULL       | NULL          | NULL       | NULL  | NULL       |
|  4 | 012334321233 | Ext : 602  | NULL          | NULL       | NULL  | NULL       |
+----+--------------+------------+---------------+------------+-------+------------+
```

Here are the list what I need :

1. remove character from tel_X, mostly '-'
2. leave extra comment on tel_X_desc
3. make not UTF-8 number to correct format, from '０１２３' to
   '0123'

I managed to MySQL create stored function for #3, however I cannot LOOP this for each records and update......

```
CREATE FUNCTION `multibyte2cv`(`str` TEXT) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
    DECLARE int_len INT(2);
    DECLARE int_z VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '１２３４５６７８９０';
    DECLARE int_h VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '1234567890';

    SET int_len = CHAR_LENGTH(int_z);
    WHILE int_len > 0 DO
        SET str = REPLACE(str, SUBSTRING(int_z,int_len,1), SUBSTRING(int_h,int_len,1));
        SET int_len = int_len - 1;
    END WHILE;
  RETURN str;
END;
```

I am pretty new to database field and trying to find something that I can solve this issue....

Comment: Would it be possible that allready on the insert you check it to not have to clean up but keep order when inserting? From design-perspective that would be much easier..

Comment: Other idea would be to do it witch a [cursor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html) but prefere barmars update

Comment: Yes, I did some research and cursor and fetch would be usable. Can I use function in another function or procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Call the function in an `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE test 
SET tel_1 = multibyte2cv(tel_1), tel_2 = multibyte2cv(tel_2), tel_3 = multibyte2cv(tel_3)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked on #3 but still need to do #1 and #2. I guess it would be easier to create another function for them and run a same code.

Comment: You can just use the `REPLACE()` function to remove specific characters like `-`. Unfortunately, there's no built-in function for removing all characters except for a certain range. You can search for a `REGEXP_REPLACE()` UDF that's useful for this, though.